# One week old lifts and turns head

Tags: newborn, development, milestones

My grand daughter is a week old and already can lift her head off her mattress or your shoulder and turn it the other way. Is this advanced?

Comment: My son did the same thing at one week. It's probably a little quicker than average, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: Yeah, it's a marathon, not a race.

Comment: You may also find that she might forget how to do it again for a while. It's not uncommon for babies to do things when they're newborns and then lose the ability for a few months.

Comment: One interesting example is the walking reflex. While holding a very tiny baby, if you touch their feet to the bed or floor etc. they'll sometimes move their little legs in a walking motion. However after a few weeks they forget how to do it.

Comment: At 6 weeks my youngest (who spent the pregnancy giving painful kicks to my wife's spine and had such leg musculature that her legs looked like giant cones of muscles) was able to stand (not balance) supporting her whole weight on her legs.  I was impressed and scared.  Every kid is so different from every other kid that learning about a single one makes you less educated about any other.  If they are active - that is good.  If they are not happy and are active, they will communicate it.

Comment: Not necessarily. I turned over the day I was born but then I only started walking at 18 months!

Comment: My little one at around 3 weeks was able to last longer laying on her belly and keeping her head up than me. And she was crying while doing it, so it's quite a remarkable feat;)

Answer (score 3):

This is within expectations for a healthy baby. Some do it this early, some don't. In general most developmental milestones have a wide range of expected times, and as long as they are roughly within this all is expected to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

My son was able to hold his head up from birth (which actually had me worried!)

When I asked the Dr I was told it was perfectly normal for some babies to be able to do that.